# Representing 3D Surfaces as Music

Tags: analysis

Is it possible to represent 3D surfaces the same way we can represent
sound, so that analysing sound is equal to analyzing a specific 3D model?

For example, music is often decomposed into frequencies via Fourier Analysis. These frequencies can then be fingerprinted and compared.

Is such a decomposition (or another) also possible for 3D models? I came across this [paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0354/f5658f76a0b176aaba5646da2bbf12eddc69.pdf) but don't understand it that much yet.

Ideally, this transformation would be rotationally invariant, so that rotating a model yields an equivalent (or similar) decomposition.

Even if they are not fleshed out, I would love to hear your ideas!

Thanks in advance!